# CSS3 Alternate table background color based on table row class

Tags: css, css-tables

There should be a good way to alternate table row background colors based on class. Currently, I'm just doing something like this:

```
/* Staff Table */
table#user_provisioning .bpink { background-color: lavenderblush; }
table#user_provisioning .fred { color: red; }
table#user_provisioning tr.Administrators, tr.ProfessionalStaff { background-color: honeydew; }
table#user_provisioning tr.Deans, tr.SupportStaff { background-color: white; }
table#user_provisioning td { text-align: left; }
```

I would think there's a way to do something like:

```
table#user_provisioning tr.{foreach class}:nth-child(odd) { background-color: honeydew; }
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to include all tr classes for the table and go even/odd based on that.

Suggestions?

Edit: Adding snipped/edited page code

```css
table#table_organization tr.unsure,
tr.dept,
tr.org {
  background-color: honeydew;
}

table#table_organization tr.board,
tr.prog,
tr.ssa {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1> Organization </h1>
  <table id="table_organization" class="sortable">
    <tr>
      <th> Dept. </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="unsure">
      <td> - </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="board">
      <td> Board </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dept">
      <td> Department </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dept">
      <td> Department </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dept">
      <td> Department </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="prog">
      <td> Program </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="prog">
      <td> Program </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="prog">
      <td> Program </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="org">
      <td> Organization </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="org">
      <td> Organization </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="org">
      <td> Organization </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ssa">
      <td> SSA </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ssa">
      <td> SSA </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ssa">
      <td> SSA </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

Comment: post your full code so we can check what is wrong with your css, only by css we cant understand what is happening, try to create a demo, you can also check this https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/ this can help you.

Comment: Added minimal page code. The :nth-of-type appears only to work with elements and not class selectors. Ideally I'd like to have something that creates a list of available classes for an element and then does an :nth-of-type on it.

Comment: i don't think so, nth-of-type will work with class selectors. i added the answer you can check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately CSS does not have a `:nth-of-class` pseudo selector. As long as the number of rows is very limited, using the adjacent sibling selector `+` could help (showing only for `.dept`):

```css
.dept {
  background: yellow;
}

.dept+.dept {
  background-color: orange;
}

.dept+.dept+.dept {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table_organization" class="sortable">
  <tr>
    <th> Dept. </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dept">
    <td> Department </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dept">
    <td> Department </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dept">
    <td> Department </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table#table_organization tr.unsure,
tr.dept:nth-of-type(odd),
tr.org {
  background-color: honeydew;
}

tr.dept:nth-of-type(even){
    background-color: red;
}

table#table_organization tr.board,
tr.prog,
tr.ssa {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1> Organization </h1>
  <table id="table_organization" class="sortable">
    <tr>
      <th> Dept. </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="unsure">
      <td> - </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="board">
      <td> Board </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dept">
      <td> Department </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dept">
      <td> Department </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dept">
      <td> Department </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="prog">
      <td> Program </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="prog">
      <td> Program </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="prog">
      <td> Program </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="org">
      <td> Organization </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="org">
      <td> Organization </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="org">
      <td> Organization </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ssa">
      <td> SSA </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ssa">
      <td> SSA </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ssa">
      <td> SSA </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```